# Library Design for Custom Performance Counters in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, performancecounter

For one of the requirement, i was told to create custom performance counters for our window service. After analysis google page i came to know about Miccrosoft .NET Library System.Diagnostics.

I am using DB tables to store my Categories and Counters Information as a master entry like category and counters name description, Category type (single/ multiple), datatype of counters etc.

Now i would like to know whether i should create new separate wrapper dll where i will load all information from database to create category and counters? Is this is correct design?

Second: Ideally who should load database? Caller program or actual program (which is creating counters and category)?

Please help me for this design?